# Missing $ inserted at \end{frame} and a bunch of other errors

Tags: errors

I have this code:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Referências}

CAVALCANTI JÚNIOR, F. de H. \textbf{Avaliação de Técnicas de Filtragem Colaborativa para Sistemas de Recomendação}. Disponível em \<https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~tg/2017-1/fhcj2-tg.pdf\>. Acesso em 07 dez. 2020.\newline
DACREMA, M. F.; CREMONESI, P. \textbf{Eigenvalue analogy for confidence estimation in item-based recommender systems}. Disponível em \<https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.02052.pdf\>. Acesso em 07 dez. 2020.\newline
GOWER, S. \textbf{Netflix Prize and SVD}. Disponível em \<http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2014spring/420projects/math420-UPS-spring-2014-gower-netflix-SVD.pdf\>. Acesso em 06 dez. 2020.\newline
JAFFALI, S. et al. \textbf{Grouping Like-Minded Users for Ratings Prediction}. Intelligent Decision Technologies, 2016. Disponível em \<https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01336507\>. Acesso em 08 dez. 2020.\newline
LIM, Y. \textbf{Math for Data Science:} Collaborative Filtering on Utility Matrices. Disponível em \<https://towardsdatascience.com/math-for-data-science-collaborative-filtering-on-utility-matrices-e62fa9badaab\>. Acesso em 08 dez. 2020.\newline
M, M. et al. \textbf{Netflix Ranking by Combination of K-Nearest Neighbour and Singular Value Decomposition}. International Journal of Computational Science and Engineering, v. 10, n. 1, p. 1-10, 2020. Disponível em \<http://www.ripublication.com/ijcse20/ijcsev10n1_01.pdf\>. Acesso em 07 dez. 2020.\newline
MIT. \textbf{Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) tutorial}. Disponível em \<https://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm\>. Acesso em 06 dez. 2020.\newline
PANTOLA, P. \textbf{Recommendation Using Matrix Factorization}. Disponível em \<https://medium.com/@paritosh_30025/recommendation-using-matrix-factorization-5223a8ee1f4\>. Acesso em 07 dez. 2020.\newline
TAE, J. \textbf{Recommendation Algorithm with SVD}. Disponível em \<https://jaketae.github.io/study/svd/\>. Acesso em 07 dez. 2020.\newline
WIKIPEDIA. \textbf{Collaborative filtering}. Disponível em \<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering\>. Acesso em 08 dez. 2020.\newline
WIKIPEDIA. \textbf{Singular value decomposition}. Disponível em \<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition\>. Acesso em 06 dez. 2020.

\end{frame}
```

And I'm getting a bunch of errors and I really don't know how to solve any of these. Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frame` environment in `beamer` reads the whole of its contents as an argument which means that a lot of errors end up showing up in the `\end{frame}` rather than where you would expect them to. In this case, the problem is the underscores in your URLs. If you replace each instance of `_` with `\_` you should get the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: @Hitagi --- You also need to define the macros `\<` and `\>`.  Alternatively, you could just use `<` and `>` (I'm guessing that your file is UTF-8 encoded, since it contains international characters).

Comment: @IanThompson Oh, you are right. It worked now!!! Thanks a lot to both of you!!! :D